# Do I need the Skia DLL in Delphi 12 Athens?

Tags: delphi, skia, skia4delphi, delphi-12-athens

With Skia being integrated into Delphi 12 natively, do I still need to ship `sk4d.dll` with my executable, or is this not needed anymore going forward with newer versions of Delphi?

Comment: For now, you need to distribute the DLL with your app. This might change in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For now, you need to distribute the Skia4Delphi DLL with your application as of version 6.0.0 of Skia4Delphi.

But the [Developers](https://github.com/skia4delphi/skia4delphi/graphs/contributors) behind [Skia4Delphi](https://github.com/skia4delphi/skia4delphi/) are working on embedding the DLL into the EXE so that it doesn't need to be distributed separately with your application.